# vc++ forms designer

Tags: visual-c++, forms, textbox

im using vc++ forms. i created a textbox, im trying to get the value in it i used textBox1->Text. all im trying to do is this create a file name text.txt than write in side the file what is inside the textBox1. here the code

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             Help::ShowPopup( button1, textBox1->Text , Point(button1->Right,this->button1->Bottom) );//works here
             ofstream a_file("test.txt");
             a_file << textBox1->Text;//get error
             a_file.close();
             if ( !a_file.is_open() )
                Help::ShowPopup( button1, "s" , Point(button1->Right,this->button1->Bottom) );

             Application::Exit;
         }
```

the error is this error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'System::String ^' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
thanks in advance
rami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix managed and unmanaged types unless this is absolutely necessary. Replace unmanaged ofstream with managed StreamWriter:

```
System::IO::StreamWriter sw = gcnew System::IO::StreamWriter(L"test.txt");
sw->WriteLine(textBox1->Text);
sw->Close();
```

Comment: well thank you very much it solved it i just added a ^ where yu declared sw in line one thanks!

Comment: sir do you know how to close the window and open new one when the button is clicked?